# Can we get the size of an element after zooming in/out?

Tags: jquery

I've a div having height and width as 100px respectively. When I zoom in using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd>, I could zoom into the div. Is there any way I can find out the width and height of the div in zoom mode?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want that? Browsers manage it well now.

Comment: I've overridden the default events with pinchopen and pinchclose using  jgesture jquery library in order to load the new higher resolution image on every pinch. But before loading the high resolution image, I want to make sure that the default zooming (in ipad) exceeds particular amount of scale. Thats why i decided to go with the way to get the size of elements in zoom mode. Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way! is like you want to get your div's size if the user is looking to the screen behind magnifying glass!